# Access violation at address 0071D1E2 in module ... . Read of address 00000000

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как добавил графики возникла ошибка, программа написана была на

```
delphi7
```

Сам код :

```
procedure TFDub2.BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if gr=3 then
 begin
 Form2.Chart1.Series[0].Clear;//Сброс
 Form2.Chart1.Series[1].Clear;//Сброс
 Form2.Chart1.Series[2].Clear;//Сброс
 Form2.Chart1.Series[3].Clear;//Сброс
 Form2.Chart1.Series[4].Clear;//Сброс
 Form2.Chart1.Series[5].Clear;//Сброс

 Kiz:=StrToFloat(Edit7.Text);
 Niz:=0;
 While Niz<=1 do
 begin

 if Niz=0 then  //Построение изолинии при опасной скорости ветра
 begin
  X:=0; jX:=0; jXY:=1; Xiz:=0; kj:=0;
  While jX<=90 do begin
   Y:=0; jY:=0;
   While jY<=90 do//Формирование цикла по переменной jy
   begin
    aY[jY]:=Y;

    //Блок расчёта коэф-та S2
    IF aX[jX]=0 then aX[jX]:=0.000001;
    Y1:=Sqr(Y/(aX[jX]*1000));

    if um>5 then tym:=5*Y1 else tym:=um*Y1;
    ty2m:=Sqr(tym);
    S2m:=1/Sqr(1+5*tym+12.8*ty2m+17*tym*ty2m+45.1*ty2m*ty2m);
    //Конец блока расчёта коэф-та S2

    yxKmp[jX,jY]:=S2m*aKmp[jX];
//   yxKcc[jX,jY]:=S2m*aKcc[jX];
//   yxKrz[jX,jY]:=S2m*aKrz[jX];

    kkj:=0;
    while kkj<90 do
    begin
     if (Kiz<aKmp[kkj+1]) and (Kiz>=aKmp[kkj]) then
     begin
      XXiz:=(90*(aX[kkj]+(Kiz-aKmp[kkj])*(aX[kkj+1]-aX[kkj])/(aKmp[kkj+1]-aKmp[kkj])))/meridian+Nl;
      ik:=kkj;
      Form2.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(XXiz,El);
      Form2.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(XXiz,El);
      kkj:=90;
     end;
     kkj:=kkj+1;
    end;

    if (Kiz>=aKmp[jX+1]) and (Kiz<aKmp[jX]) then
    begin
     Xiz:=(90*(aX[jX]+(Kiz-aKmp[jX])*(aX[jX+1]-ax[jX])/(aKmp[jX+1]-aKmp[jX])))/meridian+Nl;
     iX:=jX;
     Form2.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(Xiz,El);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(Xiz,El);
     jX:=90;
    end;

    if (Kiz>=yxKmp[jX,jy]) and (Kiz<yxKmp[jX,jY-1]) then
    begin
     Yizmp[jX,jY]:=(aY[jY-1]+(Kiz-yxKmp[jX,jY-1])*(aY[jY]-aY[jY-1])/(yxKmp[jX,jY]-yxKmp[jX,jY-1]))/parallel+El;
     if aX[jX]=2 then aX[jX]:=XXiz/1000;
     Form2.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aX[jX]*1000,Yizmp[jX,jY]);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(aX[jX]*1000,2*El-Yizmp[jX,jY]);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[4].AddXY(aX[1],Yizmp[jX,jY]*(1.5));
     Form2.Chart1.Series[5].AddXY(aX[1],2*El-Yizmp[jX,jY]*(1.5));
    end;

    //Блок вывода массива точек на ГИС
    if Yizmp[jX,jY]>0 then
    begin
     aXiz[1,jX]:=Yizmp[jX,jY]; aXiz[0,jX]:=jX*zst;
     aXYiz[jX,1]:=Yizmp[jX,jY]; aXYiz[jX,0]:=jX*zst;
    end;

    aXYiz[iX,0]:=Xiz;  aXYiz[ik,0]:=XXiz;
    //Конец блока

   Y:=Y+5; jY:=jY+1;
  end; //Конец цикла по переменной jy

  jX:=jX+1;
  end;//Конец цикла по переменной jX
 end; //Конец блока построения изолиний при опасной скорости ветра
  jj:=1;
 {-------------------------------------------------------------}

 if Niz=1 then //Построение изолинии при заданной скорости ветра
 begin
  X:=0; jX:=0; jXY:=1;
  While jX<=90 do
  begin

   Y:=0; jY:=0;
   While jY<=90 do//Формирование цикла по переменной jy
   begin
    aY[jY]:=Y;
//    aXY[jX,jy]:=Y;

    //Блок расчёта коэф-та S2
    IF aX[jX]=0 then aX[jX]:=0.000001;
    Y1:=Sqr(Y/(aX[jX]*90));

    if u>5 then ty:=5*Y1 else ty:=u*Y1;
    ty2:=Sqr(ty);
    S2:=1/Sqr(1+5*ty+12.8*ty2+17*ty*ty2+45.1*ty2*ty2);
    //Конец блока расчёта коэф-та S2

    yxKmpu[jX,jY]:=S2*aKmpu[jX];
//   yxKccu[jX,jY]:=S2*aKccu[jX];
//   yxKrzu[jX,jY]:=S2*aKrzu[jX];


    kkj:=0;
    while kkj<90 do
    begin
     if (Kiz<aKmpu[kkj+1]) and (Kiz>=aKmpu[kkj]) then
    begin
     XXizu:=(90*(aX[kkj]+(Kiz-aKmpu[kkj])*(aX[kkj+1]-ax[kkj])/(aKmpu[kkj+1]-aKmpu[kkj])))/meridian+Nl;
     iku:=kkj;
     Form2.Chart1.Series[2].AddXY(XXizu,El);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[3].AddXY(XXizu,El);
     kkj:=90;
    end;
    kkj:=kkj+1;
   end;

   if (Kiz>=aKmpu[jX+1]) and (Kiz<aKmpu[jX]) then
   begin
    Xizu:=(90*(aX[jX]+(Kiz-aKmpu[jX])*(aX[jX+1]-ax[jX])/(aKmpu[jX+1]-aKmpu[jX])))/meridian+Nl;
    iXu:=jX;
    Form2.Chart1.Series[2].AddXY(Xizu,EL);
    Form2.Chart1.Series[3].AddXY(Xizu,El);
    jX:=90;
   end;

    if (Kiz>=yxKmpu[jX,jy]) and (Kiz<yxKmpu[jX,jY-1]) then
    begin
     Yizmpu[jX,jY]:=(aY[jY-1]+(Kiz-yxKmpu[jX,jY-1])*(aY[jY]-aY[jY-1])/(yxKmpu[jX,jY]-yxKmpu[jX,jY-1]))/parallel+El;
     Form2.Chart1.Series[2].AddXY(aX[jX]*90,Yizmpu[jX,jY]);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[3].AddXY(aX[jX]*90,2*El-Yizmpu[jX,jY]);
     Form2.Chart1.Series[4].AddXY(aX[1],Yizmpu[jX,jY]*(1.5));
     Form2.Chart1.Series[5].AddXY(aX[1],2*El-Yizmpu[jX,jY]*(1.5));
    end;

    //Блок вывода массива точек на ГИС
    if Yizmpu[jX,jY]>0 then
    begin
     aXizu[1,jX]:=Yizmpu[jX,jY]; aXizu[0,jX]:=jX*zst;
     aXYizu[jX,1]:=Yizmpu[jX,jY]; aXYizu[jX,0]:=jX*zst;
    end;

    aXYizu[iXu,0]:=Xizu;  aXYizu[iku,0]:=XXizu;
    //Конец блока

   Y:=Y+5; jY:=jY+1;
  end; //Конец цикла по переменной jy


  jX:=jX+1;
  end;//Конец цикла по переменной jX
 end;  //Конец блока построения изолиний при опасной скорости ветра

  Niz:=Niz+1;
 end; //Конец цикла по Niz

 jj:=1;
 Form2.Label1.Caption:=Edit7.Text;
 Form2.Label2.Caption:=ckm+' м/с;';
 Form2.Label3.Caption:=ck+' м/с';
 Form2.Show;
 end else
 FDub6.Show;
end; //Конец процедуры построения изолиний
```

Код формы с графиками:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, VclTee.TeeGDIPlus, VCLTee.TeEngine,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, VCLTee.TeeProcs, VCLTee.Chart, Vcl.StdCtrls, VCLTee.Series;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Chart1: TChart;
    Series1: TLineSeries;
    Series2: TLineSeries;
    Series3: TLineSeries;
    Series4: TLineSeries;
    StaticText1: TStaticText;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
//label1:=Dub3.Edit7.Text
procedure TForm2.BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Chart1.Series[0].Clear;//Сброс
 Chart1.Series[1].Clear;//Сброс
 Chart1.Series[2].Clear;//Сброс
 Chart1.Series[3].Clear;//Сброс
 if CloseQuery then Close;
end;
end.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина появления ошибки, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: В первую очередь - нужно собрать приложение в Debug-конфигурации, запустить внутри IDE (F9) и посмотреть в Call Stack- окне, на какой строке кода возникает ошибка. После этого можно уже анализировать - почему она там возникает. AV - это чаще всего обращение к несуществующему объекту. Который был не создан или удален

Comment: у вас там серий всего 4, а в начале очищаете 6.

Comment: Спасибо. Там в кнопке было дело скорей всего. Сейчас только это понял. Я написал код, а сам её не создал. Сейчас выводит график)